# Export/Backup SharePoint Online Term Store using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

If someone can help me that would be great. I have searched online and can't seem to find what I'm looking for. We are currently working with our SharePoint online sites and have migrated most sites. I'm looking for a PowerShell script to run on a weekly basis to backup the SPO term store just in case we need to restore for some reason.

Does anyone know of a PowerShell script that can do this? Backup the SPO term store effectively and for easy use of restore in case something goes wrong?

Also if someone does have a script can they also provide instructions on how to use it to restore to a site?

Thanks in advance!
Clare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are also the following cmdlets from [SharePoint PnP PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps):

- [Export-PnPTaxonomy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/export-pnptaxonomy?view=sharepoint-ps)
- [Import-PnPTaxonomy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/import-pnptaxonomy?view=sharepoint-ps)

You can use them to import and export the taxonomy store and it's data. Just remember to run `Connect-PnPOnline` to signin.

Answer (score 0):

Check the sample command [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/import-or-export-taxonomy-term-sets-using-pnp-powershell/).

`Export-SPOTaxonomy` and `Import-SPOTermGroupFromXml`